# Question on Dart language regarding function

Tags: flutter, dart

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NMjy.jpg)

```
void main() {
int printit(var y, var z){
    var c = y+10;
    print (y);
    return c;
  }
 
  printit(20,23);
 
 var b = printit(1,3);
 print (b);
}
```

Why does the above code in DartPad gives output as this?

```
20
1
11
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWI2i.jpg)

Why does it *prints the function* **for the second time** when I am trying to add the return value of the function to a variable 'b'?

Comment: Your question is why prints `11`?

Answer (score 0):

It prints it because you call `print(b)` in the following line.

Remove the line and the output should be as below:

```
20
1
```

Comment: That's not my question. When I'm asking to print (b), it should give me 11 as output. Why it prints 1 on the second line? (Ignore first line in output)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code snippet below

```
void main() {

int printit(var y, var z){
    var c = y+10;
    return c;
  }

var b;
 
 b= printit(20,23);

 print (b);
 
 b = printit(1,3);

 print (b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints `1` because you assigned to `b` the value `printit(1,3)` and in your function itself you ask for printing `y` (here `1`) with `print(y)`.

```
void main() {
int printit(var y, var z){
    var c = y+10;
    print (y); // this line is responsible for printing 1. Try removing this.
    return c;
  }
 
  printit(20,23);
 
 var b = printit(1,3);
 print (b);
}
```